# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre una función con parámetro void y una función sin parámetros?

Tags: c

Me han dicho y he leído que una función con parámetro `void` es una función que no recibe parámetros

```
int func(void);
```

Sin embargo, no se cuál es la diferencia de declararla sin parámetro alguno, es decir dejar los paréntesis en blanco

```
int func();
```

Entonces me surgen las preguntas:

- ¿Hay deferencia alguna entre las dos maneras?
- ¿Por que debería de declarar una función con void y no con los paréntesis vacíos?

Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Hay deferencia alguna entre las dos maneras?

Específicamente en C, cuando una función se define sin argumentos (los paréntesis vacíos), **no significa que no reciba argumentos.** Realmente significa

- Cualquier cantidad de argumentos
- Argumentos de cualquier tipo de dato

Al definir una función sin argumentos, y luego llamar dicha función con argumentos:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func() {
    printf("Finalizido");
}

int main(void) {
    func("foo","bar");    
}
```

El compilador tan solo mostrara una simple advertencia:

```
warning: too many arguments in call to 'func'
```

---

Por otro lado un argumento `void`, es la **manera explicita para el compilador de definir una función sin argumentos.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(void) {
    printf("Finalizido");
}

int main(void) {
    func("foo","bar");    
}
```

Al definir una función con argumento `void` y llamarla con algún argumento, se obtendrá un error.

```
error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 2
```

El compilador directamente, no permite esto.

> ¿Por que debería de declarar una función con void y no con los paréntesis vacíos?

Al declarar una función sin argumentos, se deja abierta la posibilidad de que la función reciba algún argumento. Esto elimina la [seguridad de tipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), se tiene que evitar en lo posible.

Answer (score 1):

El [estándar de C](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) indica que las funciones con `void` en la lista de parámetros son un caso especial (traducción y resaltados míos):

> 6.9.1 Definición de funciones
>
> ---
>
> **Restricciones**
>
> 5. Si la declaración incluye una lista de tipos de parámetros, la declaración de cada parámetro debe incluir un identificador **excepto para el caso especial de una lista de parámetros consistente en un único parámetro de tipo `void`**, en cuyo caso no debe haber identificador. No debe haber una lista de declaraciones a continuación.

En otras palabras, el estándar de [c](/questions/tagged/c) indica que las funciones que no reciben parámetros se definen con `void` en la lista de parámetros ya que:

- El parámetro `void` no tendrá identificadores.
- El parámetro `void` no tendrá lista de declaraciones.